# Error when building task with GCC compiler on vs code, Windows [Gtk Libraries] - Error adding symbols

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, gcc, build-error

When i run build task from the terminal in vs code i get this error:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lpangowin64-1.0
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/libmingw32.a: error adding symbols: File format not recognized
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Build finished with error(s).
```

Here's my c_cpp_properies.json (only includePaths):
(All the include paths are taken from pkgconf --cflags)

```
"includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include\\gtk-4.0\\gtk",
                "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include\\gtk-3.0\\gtk",
                "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include\\pango-1.0",
                "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include\\**",
                "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include\\glib-2.0",
                "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include\\harfbuzz",
                "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include\\freetype2",
                "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include\\libpng16",
                "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include\\fribidi",
                "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include\\cairo",
                "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include\\lzo",
                "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include\\pixman-1",
                "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include\\gdk-pixbuf-2.0",
                "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include\\webp",
                "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include\\graphene-1.0",
                "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\lib\\gtk-4.0",
                "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\lib\\glib-2.0",
                "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\lib\\**"
            ],
```

And here's tasks.json(only args (from pkgconf --libs)):

```
"args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                    "-I${includePath <all elements>}",
                "${file}",
                    "-lgtk-4",
                    "-lpangowin64-1.0", 
                    "-lpangocairo-1.0", 
                    "-lpango-1.0", 
                    "-lharfbuzz", 
                    "-lgdk_pixbuf-2.0", 
                    "-lcairo-gobject", 
                    "-lcairo",
                    "-lgraphene-1.0", 
                    "-lgio-2.0",
                    "-lgobject-2.0", 
                    "-lglib-2.0",
                    "-lintl", 
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            ],
```

I have installed all the necessary libraries such as gtk4, toolchain base_devel, glib all from msys64 console

How do i solve this error ?

PS: Aim is to build a GUI based program using C, i have now selected GTK, any alternatives are appreciated too. Also should i switch from VS Code for a better environment ?

Comment: yes vs code has better environment than any other alternative

Comment: @nischalsharma thank you for the input, do you have any insight on the error I am facing ?

Comment: Does your file actually say `"-I${includePath <all elements>}"`? Or did you just type it that way in your question to save space? I have never seen such syntax before. Should it not be one `-I <path>` for each include directory?

Comment: @user no it was written to save space Sorry for being so vague

Comment: please use actual synax to avoid confusion. see also the instructions on providing a [mre]